# width of child div is larger than parent

Tags: html, css

I need my child div to stick to the bottom of the parent div, hence the `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0px`. I also need the child width to be the same as the parent, and I thought `box-sizing: border-box` would work, but the width of the child still protrudes to the right, due to the padding and margins.

How do I fix this?

```css
.parent {
  height: 500px;
  min-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbmq6z5a/3/)

Comment: Hello, 
You have `margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px,` then, the width should be `100% - 20px`, in css : `width: calc(100% - 20px);`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `left:0`/`right:0` instead of `width:100%` to avoid overflow due to margin as actually your element is taking 500px + 20px(of margin left/right) inside the parent element.

As a side note, `box-sizing: border-box` is working perfectly but **inside** the element so padding are included in the width but margin of course not:

> border-box tells the browser to account for any **border** and
>   **padding** in the values you specify for width and height ... <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)</sup>

```css
.parent {
  height: 500px;
  min-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your thinking was correct. The margin property moves elements from their original position with the help of left, top, right and bottom. More importantly, margin does not obey container boundary restriction.

Please check the code below. In order to contain the child within the parent while keeping margin properties, you should reduce the total width of the child.

**CSS3 calc** is awesome for working with two different units. `calc(100% - 20px)` will give you the correct width.

```css
.parent {
  height: 500px;
  min-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 20px); //Subtracting left and right margin from the total width to avoid overflowing the parent container
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Subtracting left and top margin` --> should be left and right

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the margin in the child class to margin: 0
This will shift the child div to the left and down so that the bottom left corner of the child aligns with the bottom left corner of the parent.